# Linux; How do I find logs if a program I'm running uses certain ports?

Tags: linux, firewall, ports

I am running CentOS 5 with csf firewall.  I'm running a program that can't connect to another server (using some port that is blocked by csf I presume).  Where is the log file for 'ports'?

Comment: You may have better luck on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Hi:This might be off-topic, but you can verify current port status by issuing: netstat -tap and see which ports are being used. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat#Examples) is the command to use to get ports and network activity. To diagonise server processes I usually use:

```
netstat -tln
```

This yields port **numbers** in **tcp** mode **listening**. To identify associated processes you can also use -p to grab the **pid**. Here is the IANA [ports list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer right after searching a few more threads.

```
# tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Shows the UDP message but not the port.... Hmm....

Comment: Because UDP does not usually have specific ports except for well-known protocols.

Comment: Btw I overlooked this---- the above command actually showed the port.  It was labeled "DPORT"

Comment: Is this correct? I thought it meant dynamic (port) for some reason.